# kafka stream with AWS Glue - authorization issue

Tags: python, apache-kafka, aws-glue, spark-streaming-kafka

I want to stream a kafka topic from Glue job but I got the following error

> StreamingQueryException: Not authorized to access topics:
> [topic_name]

This my current script

```
# Script generated for node Kafka Stream
dataframe_KafkaStream_node1 = glueContext.create_data_frame.from_options(
    connection_type="kafka",
    connection_options={
        "connectionName": "corp_cli_kafka_connection",
        "classification": "json",
        "startingOffsets": "latest",
        "topicName": "topic_name",
        "inferSchema": "true",
        "typeOfData": "kafka"
    },
    transformation_ctx="dataframe_KafkaStream_node1",
)
```

How to set the SASL JAAS config ?

```
"kafka.bootstrap.servers": "server_url:9092",
"kafka.sasl.jaas.config": "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=XXXXXXXXXX password=XXXXXXXXXXXX;",
"kafka.sasl.mechanism": "PLAIN",
"kafka.security.protocol": "SASL_SSL"
```

Comment: The issue is here is not with Authentication and related to Authorization which indicates the credentials you are using doesn't have access to topic that you are trying to access.

Comment: But we need to add the JAAS config to the connection_options !

Comment: @NadimYounes you need a valid connection between your aws accnt and kafka cluster, for the kafka config you can set it using pyspark as the following

Comment: df.selectExpr(
        "CAST(id AS STRING) AS key", "to_json(struct(metadata,payload)) AS value"
    ).write.format("kafka").option("topic", topic).option(
        "kafka.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm", "https"
    ).option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", bootstrap_server)
.option( "kafka.sasl.jaas.config",
        f'org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="{username}" password="{password}";', 
    ).option(
        "kafka.sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN"
    ).option( "kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_SSL"
    ).mode("append").save()